# How do I wakeup Java timer after windows wakeup?

Tags: java, timer, schedule

I have written a small tool that asks my printer every 5 seconds for a status. Works good. I am using Windows 7. When the machine goes into sleep mode and wakes up again, the timer of my Java has stopped running. The Java itself is definetely operating after wakeup, just the timer is dead. How do I let the timer go on too? Here is my code:

```
public class PrinterTray {
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            try{
                updateStatusFromPrinter();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void updateStatusFromPrinter() throws IOException
    {
        // do something incredible
    }

    public PrinterTray(int seconds) throws IOException {
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), 0, seconds*1000);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int seconds = 5;
        new PrinterTray(seconds);
    }
}
```